# What sort of syntax is this?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
public class MyViewModelClass
{
   public string Name { set;get;}
} 

public ActionResult MyAction()
{
  return View(new MyViewModelClass());
}

@model MyViewModelClass
@using(Html.BeginForm())
{
  MyAction Name : @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
  <input type="submit" value="Generate report" />
}
```

Could anyone tell me what the following line do?:

```
MyAction Name : @Html.TextBoxFor(s=>s.Name)
```

OK, the first word is just specifying the action to perform, but I don't get why someone needed to put 'Name' in this expression and follow it by a colon. Yes, I know what TextBoxFor does.

I've never seen syntax like this before in any ASP.NET tutorial, maybe you can give me some links where I can find more about it. Thanks!

Comment: `MyAction Name : ` is just a label... it's not a function or anything

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are seeing is the [`Razor`](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/overview/getting-started/introducing-razor-syntax-%28c%29) syntax which allows you to add C# (or VB, depending on what you're using) code in your HTML using the `@` character. It also comes with a bunch of helpful classes such as the `HtmlHelper` class you asked about (more on this below).

As far as this line is concerned:

```
MyAction Name : @Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Name)
```

The `MyAction Name :` part will simply print `"MyAction Name :"` in your HTML. The `@Html.TextBoxFor(s => s.Name)` part utilises the [`TextBoxFor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)  method of the [`HtmlHelper`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.htmlhelper%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) class from the `System.Web.Mvc` namespace to render a `TextBox` for the `Name` property of your `MyViewModelClass` (which is declared as the model of your view using the `@model` directive) in your HTML markup.

I've added some links which will help make things clear for you and get you up to speed in no time.

Answer (score 1):

That's a simple string:

```
MyAction Name : @Html.TextBoxFor(s=> s.Name)
```

So first you see `MyAction Name :` in the result then `@Html.TextBoxFor(s=> s.Name)` generates a text box after that.

Comment: i think you're confusing textboxfor with displayfor